Meaning of 'of' in "how good of a life”
This sentence appears on a certain website. I'm curious about the meaning of 'of' in this sentence. Is it by any chance the meaning 5b 'in respect to' from Webster's Dictionary?

It really gives you perspective on how good of a life you live when you hear about stories like this.


Using 'of' after an adjective in phrases like 'how good of a life', 'how big of a car', is a mainly US English thing. It is controversial. Many grammar and usage guides say that it is an error in standard English.

Yes, M+W sense 5b in respect to is the meaning used here.
Cambridge Dictionary sense c1 has a similar example with this meaning of of:

about; relating to


Of her childhood we know very little.

of

I do not think you have answered the question sufficiently.

Sorry, but I found the answer I was looking for on Wiktionary. Thanks to everyone who replied to my question and to those who commented and edited my post!

10.4 Expressing qualities or characteristics.(US, informal, considered incorrect by some) Used to link singular indefinite nouns
(preceded by the indefinite article) and attributive adjectives
modified by certain common adverbs of degree.
It's not that big of a deal.


Usage note : The use of of to link nouns to attributive adjectives
modified by certain adverbs is always optional; omitting of in such
instances is always permissible and does not alter the meaning of the
expression. Adverbs that may be used with this construction include
too, so, how, as, more, less, this, and that.

